# Sequence cache size

Tags: postgresql, sequence

I have to change cache for all sequences in schema and database. I can not change one by one. Is there some script or query which can change cache size for all sequences?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `DO` statement so that you can run a PL/pgSQL block in a single SQL statement:

```
DO
$$DECLARE
   v_schema text;
   v_sequence text;
BEGIN
   FOR v_schema, v_sequence IN
      SELECT sequence_schema, sequence_name
      FROM information_schema.sequences
      WHERE sequence_schema = 'myschema'
   LOOP
      EXECUTE format('ALTER SEQUENCE %I.%I CACHE 20',
                     v_schema, v_sequence);
   END LOOP;
END;$$;
```

Comment: Yes I changed to public schema and I get the following: Error report -
Unterminated dollar quote started at position 283 in SQL BEGIN
   FOR v_schema, v_sequence IN.....I have hundreds of sequences but just give example for two.THNX
      SELECT sequence_schema, sequence_name
      FROM information_schema.sequences
      WHERE sequence_schema = 'public'
   LOOP
      EXECUTE format('ALTER SEQUENCE %I.%I CACHE 20',
                     v_schema, v_sequence);
   END LOOP;
END;$$;. Expected terminating $$

Comment: Are you using `psql` as client? If not, maybe your client cannot digest dollar quoted strings correctly. In that case, use a different client. I'll edit the answer to avoid dollar quoting.

Comment: Dear Laurenz, i have connection to my postgres database via sql developer 18.4.Thank you

Comment: That's probably your problem.

Comment: When I run code i get this: DECLARE
   v_schema text,
   v_sequence text;
BEGIN
   FOR v_schema, v_sequence IN
      SELECT sequence_schema, sequence_name
      FROM information_schema.sequences
      WHERE sequence_schema = ''public''
   LOOP
      EXECUTE format(''ALTER SEQUENCE %I.%I CACHE 20'',
                     v_schema, v_sequence);
   END LOOP;
END;;
Error report -
ERROR: syntax error at or near "text"
  Position: 21 (I have to remove (') before DECLARE statement because with this all my code is blue color and unusable)...

Comment: That client is just broken. It thinks that a `;` inside a string literal ends the SQL statement. Do yourself a favor and use something else.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz for help.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach which is often adequate is to generate all the statements in a query and then just copy and paste them to run them. This way you can customize the statements for each occasion. The queries are simple enough that you don't even need to save the code for future use.

```
SELECT 'alter sequence ' || sequence_schema || '.' || sequence_name || ' cache 20;'
FROM information_schema.sequences;
```

It should be obvious you can use this "trick" for other object types too.